# how to get running mediaStream

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia, mediastream

I've created a webCam Stream with

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ "video": true }, function(stream){
    videoTag.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    videoTag.play();
}
```

**Can I access the MediaStream object in `stream` in global scope?***

(something like `navigator.getAllMediaStreams[0]`)

*edit: ...without adding logic to the getUserMedia function. My problem case is a qr-decoder-library, that gets the stream for me and I don't want to change the third party code

Comment: This question is based on a deprecated API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no list of active media streams kept by the browser.

You can save the stream to for example window.stream.

Comment: "There is no list kept by the browser" might answer my background question (see edit), so I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
navigator.allMediaStreams = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ "video": true }).then(stream => {
  navigator.allMediaStreams.push(stream);
  console.log(navigator.allMediaStreams.length); // 1
})
.catch(e => console.error(e));

console.log(navigator.allMediaStreams.length); // 0
```

Just understand that the array will be empty until the success callback fires.

It's like any other JavaScript object. As long as you keep a reference to a stream (so it doesn't get garbage collected), and don't call `stop()` on its tracks, you'll have a live video stream at your disposal, and the active-camera light, if there is one, will be on during this time.

Also like any other JavaScript variable, it is still tied to the page, even if it hangs off `navigator`, so it won't survive page navigation.