# JavaScript to Determine Active Network Streams in Browser

Tags: javascript, networking, stream

I'm trying to determine when a page has finished being updated dynamically. (For example, DevTools shows the waterfall under the 'Network' tab, which downloads the data for a few seconds before completing.)

Do I need to use the Resource Timing API, or is there a better solution?

(Note: I'm not a native JavaScript user. I'm using Edge, as I'm working with a WebView2 control in C#. Edge, however, does support the Resource Timing API.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get running mediaStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930537/how-to-get-running-mediastream)